# Google Play Store is not working

Tags: google-play-store

I updated my Galaxy S3 three months ago and since then, my Play Store went wrong. I can't open it anymore, not to mention my phone often got stuck for hours. I tried every method I could find like resetting the phone, cancel Google account but it just wouldn't work. I can still open apps that I downloaded before, but I can't update them. What should I do to make it back to normal again?

Comment: By "resetting the phone", do you mean a Factory Reset?

Comment: Is the device rooted? You could reflash the gapps package. Alternatively clear the data, uninstall updates as SilverlightFox suggested.

Comment: restore your device or
clear google play data from app manager
or install another google play app

Answer (score 2):

Try going to `Settings` > `Applications Manager` > `All` > `Google Play Store` and then click `Uninstall updates`.

It could be that the Play Store data has been corrupted. This will downgrade Play Store and might make it possible for you to launch Play Store which will then update itself in the background, but hopefully correctly this time.